# Showing that the $\mathcal{N=2}$ SUSY Effective Action is Duality-Invariant

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, supersymmetry, duality, seiberg-witten-theory

The effective action of the $\mathcal{N}=2$ supersymmetric $SU(2)$ gauge theory contains the following term;

$$Im\int d^{4}xd^{2}\theta d^{2}\bar{\theta}\Phi^{\dagger}\mathcal{F}'(\Phi)$$

Where $\Phi$ is a superfield, $\mathcal{F}$ is some (holomorphic), function and $\mathcal{F}'(\Phi)=\frac{d\mathcal{F}}{d\Phi}$.

Define $$\Phi_{D}=\mathcal{F}'(\Phi)\quad \text{and}\quad \mathcal{F}_{D}'(\Phi_{D})=-\Phi.$$

According to [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0101055) paper, we have;

$$
Im\int d^{4}xd^{2}\theta d^{2}\bar{\theta}\Phi^{\dagger}\mathcal{F}'(\Phi)
=
Im\int d^{4}xd^{2}\theta d^{2}\bar{\theta}\Phi^{\dagger}_{D}\mathcal{F}_{D}'(\Phi_{D})\tag{9.7}
$$
So that this term is invariant under the transformation.

Plugging in the definitions of $\Phi_{D}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{D}$, we have;

$$
Im\int d^{4}xd^{2}\theta d^{2}\bar{\theta}\Phi^{\dagger}\mathcal{F}'(\Phi)
=
Im\int d^{4}xd^{2}\theta d^{2}\bar{\theta}(-\mathcal{F}_{D}'(\Phi_{D}))^{\dagger}\Phi_{D}
$$

So I need to show that (up to a total derivative), $-(\mathcal{F}_{D}'(\Phi_{D}))^{\dagger}\Phi_{D}=\Phi^{\dagger}\mathcal{F}'(\Phi).$

I feel like this should be immediate, but I just can't seem to make it work.

I have tried integrating by parts, as well as the following formal manipulation;

$$
-\left(\frac{d\mathcal{F}_{D}}{d\Phi_{D}}(\Phi_{D})\right)^{\dagger}\Phi_{D}
=
-\Phi_{D}^{\dagger}\left(\frac{d\mathcal{F}_{D}}{d\Phi_{D}}\right)^{\dagger}\Phi_{D}
=
\Phi_{D}^{\dagger}\left(\frac{d\mathcal{F}_{D}}{d\Phi_{D}}\right)\Phi_{D}
=
\Phi_{D}^{\dagger}\mathcal{F}'_{D}(\Phi_{D}).
$$
Integrating by parts didn't go anywhere, and I have been unable to justify either of the first two equalities above (I am including them only for completeness as far as my attempts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Eq. (9.7) follows from the [involutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) properties of the [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) $$F(\phi)\quad\longrightarrow \quad-F_D(\phi_D)~:=~\phi\phi_D - F(\phi),\tag{A}$$
   which is spelled out in eq. (9.6). Note the extra minus in the definition (A).
2. The minus disappears again because $${\rm Im}(\bar{z})~=~-{\rm Im}(z).\tag{B}$$